# Use sscanf() to truncate string

Tags: c, scanf

If I want to get a substring between "/" "@", this one will work:

```
char buf[512] ="" ;
char src[512] = "iios/12DDWDFF@122";

sscanf( src, "%*[^/]/%[^@]", buf);
printf("%s\n", buf);          //buf will be "12DDWDFF"
```

How can I get same result from "//^&#@iios////12DDWDFF@@@@122/&*@(@///";

```
char buf2[512] ="" ;
char src[512] = "//^&#@iios////12DDWDFF@@@@122/&*@(@///";

sscanf(src, "%*[4][^/]/%[4][^@]", buf2);
printf("%s\n", buf2);         //buf2 gets nothing
```

or

```
sscanf(src, "%*[^////]/////%[^@@@@]", buf2);
printf("%s\n", buf2);         //buf2 gets nothing
```

Comment: The `scanf` family of functions are not really suited for advanced parsing, try looking for other functions that may work to find e.g. the `"////"` and `"@@@@"` sequences and how to extract the data between. [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) and [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) maybe?

Comment: if the start and end char sequences are unique, then you can use `strstr()` to obtain pointers to the start/end of the desired string.   If the start/end char sequences are not unique, then it will be very difficult to extract a specific sub string that is delimited by variable char sequences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your `sscanf` statement as follows -

```
if(sscanf(src,"%*[^0-9]%[^@]",buf2)==1)
 {
     //do something
 }
```

`%*[^0-9]` will read until number is encountered and then discard it , and `%[^@]` will read into `buf2` until `@` is encountered.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/5jclX8)

Comment: Thanks! But what if src is "//^&#345@Fiios////12DDWDFF@@@@122/&*@(@///"

Comment: @MinKim If `src` is not in constant format . then you should probably follow Joachim Plieborg's comment .

Comment: @MinKim Great Cheers !! :-)